# Extiting the ARKit view

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios4, augmented-reality

I'm trying to work with ARKit in order to enable Augmented Reality in one of my applications.

I'm able to add the ARViewController by doing this :

```
ParkingAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ParkingAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
arvc = [[ARViewController alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
//add the button to the view
[arvc.view addSubview:button];
[[appDelegate window] addSubview:arvc.view];
```

But I can't removing it and go back to my app ...

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: I tried to use some methods with :
- dismiss modal controller
- removeFromSuperView

But it didn't work ... Have you any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be similar to adding/removing controller & it's view.

I.e. you dispose the VC, but its' view is still keep by UIWindow.

```
- (void) hideController {
   //[arvc willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
   [arvc.view removeFromSuperview];
   arvc = nil; //[arvc removeFromParentViewController];
}
```